# Connect to OpenOffice Database from C#

Tags: c#, database, hsqldb, openoffice-base

I am using Open office database and want to connect data from table in C#, I used connection string "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=E:\work\HP_Data.odb", but at the run time shows an error "The 'Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine".

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your approach is going to work, even if you do manage to get the Jet.OLEDB driver properly registered on your machine. The Jet.OLEDB driver is for connecting to Jet (Access) `.mdb` files, not OpenOffice `.odb` files.

I believe that OpenOffice Base uses the [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) database engine, so you may be able to connect to your `.odb` file from C# using an HSQLDB driver.

Comment: I am not using Ms Access, I am  using Open Office, Please suggest me , how to connect with office from C#.net.

Comment: @ManjeetSingh I have re-tagged your question.